# Firebase secure updating of sensitive data

Tags: security, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am building a site that works on a balance system where the user will pay me and their balance on the site will be updated. They can use this balance to purchase items on the site. I am using firebase to store their balance in this form:

```
root
----users
--------<uid>
------------balance: 10...
```

With these rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When the user buys something on the site, I want the system to be able to automatically subtract a value from their balance in firebase, but with my current rules a malicious user with knowledge of firebase would be able to write their own app to edit their balance.

Is there a way for my app to be able to automatically update their balance when they deposit or buy something in a way that is secure and cant be done by anyone?

Note: I am new to firebase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look into [Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) to write some backend code in a secure environment.  You could write a Cloud Function that triggers on a write at a database location where the user has that access.  Then, when your function triggers, it has access to an "admin" reference that has write access to other database locations where your users can only read.

In this way, you can effectively implement a sort of "command queue" so that actions your users take can make changes anywhere in the database, using logic that only you control.

Comment: Maybe I'm not following correctly, but wouldn't I have the same problem? Couldn't a malicious user write to that trigger location which would in turn trigger my cloud function?

Comment: You can validate whether or not that trigger was valid, since only you control the code in the function.  You have to isolate all logic that determines the validity of the action this way.

Comment: What ways are commonly used to validate if it is a valid trigger? I'm unsure of how I could validate it.

Comment: It's entirely up to the requirements of your app.  Every one will be different.